# setTimeout gets faster and faster - how do I pause it?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have this script here, and it works great. Once the element scrolls into view, it transforms the element by scrolling it up. But I can't get it to stop once it scrolls out of view, and what's worse, it gets faster and faster every time it scrolls into view! How do I reset the timeout? Clearly I'm using clearTimeout wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                reviewScroll();
            } else {
                stopReviewScroll();
                //What do I put here to pause reviewScroll?
            }
        });
});

var reviewscroller = document.querySelector('.ReviewList__reviewCardContainer__1hiY0');

function reviewScroll() {
    reviewscroller.style.opacity = 1;
    i++;
    reviewscroller.style.transform = 'translate3D(0px, -'+i+'px , 0px)';
    opac = i * .001;
    reviewscroller.style.opacity = 1-opac;
    clearTimeout(setTimeout(reviewScroll, 40));
    setTimeout(reviewScroll, 40);
    if (reviewscroller.style.opacity < -0.25) {
        reviewscroller.opacity = 1;
        i = 0;
        reviewscroller.style.transform = 'translate3D(0px, -'+i+'px , 0px)';
    }
}

function stopReviewScroll() {
    clearTimeout(reviewScroll);
}

document.querySelectorAll('.ReviewList__reviewCardContainer__1hiY0').forEach(image => { observer.observe(image); });
```

Comment: `clearTimeout` needs to take a timeout id, not an element. Assign `setTimeout` to a variable and pass it that.

Comment: `clearTimeout(setTimeout(reviewScroll, 40));` What were you expecting here? Maybe just take a little more time to study the docs for those functions.

Comment: As mentioned, `clearTimeout(setTimeout(reviewScroll, 40))` doesn't make sense: you set a timeout which returns an integer as it's id, and immediately you clear it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are multiple elements that get scrolled?
How about passing them into `reviewScroll()` like so: `reviewScroll(entry)`?
Also, what is `i` and where is it declared and initialized?
Time out only fires once, after so-and-so many ms.
If you need to clear it, then set a global variable before it's first setting: `var myTimeout;`, and then use `clearTimeout(myTimeout)` when necessary, and `myTimeout=setTimeout(reviewScroll, 40)`.
40 is kind of fast... test with 2000 to see that the code works, then decrease it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be canceling the old timer and installing a new one, like so:

```js
var timerId = null;

function reviewScroll() {

    // ...

    if (timerId) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
    timerId = setTimeout(reviewScroll, 40);

    // ...

}
```

Comment: After the first `setTimeout`, `timerId` will never be `null`, `0`, or anything else `false`y...